# Get ProgID of notepad++ in order to use it with the DefaultAppAssociations.xml in Windows 10

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, dism

We would like to set a few default app associations via GPO. Apparently in Windows 10, you can set all default apps on your image and then export an XML with DISM.exe which contains all associations.

```
Dism.exe /online /export-defaultappassociations:C:\AppAssociations.xml
```

You can then use this file in the GPO **Set a default associations configuration file**.

However, notepad++ does neither show up in the control panel for default apps nor in the exported xml.

Is there any way I could set file type associations for notepad++ using this xml file?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to simply install notepad++ on a computer after that, from Settings > Apps > Default apps, pair the file extension you need to notepad++. Last step, from this same computer, export the xml file:

```
Dism /Online /Export-DefaultAppAssociations:[path\defaultassociations.xml]
```

you'll have what you're looking for.

Comment: I tried that already. Unfortunately, Notepad++ does not show up in the exported XML.